# on message event in cog dosent work (discord.py)

Tags: python, events, discord.py

Bot does not even print the messages from the on_message event and i cannot understand why (no errors or something just nothing happens).

```
 @commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message, ctx):
        print(message)
        if message.author.id == self.bot.user:
            return
        msg_content = message.content.lower()

        CurseWord = ['curse1', 'curse2']

        # delete curse word if match with the list
        if msg_content in CurseWord:
            await message.delete()
            await ctx.send("Dont say that again"
```

i cant find any errors and so i cannot understand where the problem at

Comment: Do you have intents enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_message` only takes one argument, being the `message`. You can't just add random arguments to events and expect it to work. How would the library know what to pass in?

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message

Also if you don't get any errors you probably didn't configure logging probably, or you've overridden the error handler & you're not handling that type of error. Docs on logging: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html?highlight=logging